# is_array() returns false on SimpleXml array element

Tags: php, simplexml

I try to check if SimpleXml element is an array.
I saw the given examples [here](http://php.net/manual/fr/ref.simplexml.php) on PHP doc and so it seems possible to check if a node is an array. But in my case, I cannot do it.

A `var_dump($myElement)` gives me:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#701 (4) { 
    ["@attributes"]=> array(1) { 
        ["id"]=> string(7) "5831377" 
    } 
    ["openPeriod"]=> string(10) "2016-04-01" 
    ["closePeriod"]=> string(10) "2016-05-31" 
    ["periods"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#703 (1) { 
        ["period"]=> array(2) { 
            [0]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#707 (3) { 
                ["startPeriod"]=> string(8) "10:00:00" 
                ["endPeriod"]=> string(8) "12:30:00" 
                ["weekDays"]=> string(51) "monday,tuesday,wednesday,thursday,friday,saturday,sunday" 
            } 
            [1]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#702 (3) { 
                ["startPeriod"]=> string(8) "14:00:00" 
                ["endPeriod"]=> string(8) "20:00:00" 
                ["weekDays"]=> string(51) "monday,tuesday,wednesday,thursday,friday,saturday,sunday" 
            } 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Depending `$myElement`, `$myElement->periods->period` could be an object or an array.

But in the given case, `debug(is_array($myElement->periods->period))` returns `false`.

Could you tell me why?

**EDIT**
Here is the original XML element:

```
<openingPeriod id="5831487">
    <openPeriod>2016-04-01</openPeriod>
    <closePeriod>2016-05-31</closePeriod>
    <periods>
        <period>
            <startPeriod>10:00:00</startPeriod>
            <endPeriod>12:30:00</endPeriod>
            <weekDays>monday,tuesday,wednesday,thursday,friday,saturday,sunday</weekDays>
        </period>
        <period>
            <startPeriod>14:00:00</startPeriod>
            <endPeriod>20:00:00</endPeriod>
            <weekDays>monday,tuesday,wednesday,thursday,friday,saturday,sunday</weekDays>
        </period>
    </periods>
</openingPeriod>
```

Comment: what is ur PHP version!

Comment: @Naincy, I use PHP7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your underlying assumption is wrong:

> Depending $myElement, $myElement->periods->period could be an object or an array.

The result of the `->` operator on a SimpleXMLElement object is *always* another SimpleXMLElement object. I'm not sure why there's so many mentions of `is_array` in the comments of the page you linked to, but I think they're all just making the same mistake. You may be fooled by `var_dump` or `print_r` telling you there's an array, but it's lying; that's just how *the debug info* displays multiple items with the same name.

You can access the object *as though it was an array*, using `[0]`, `foreach`, etc, but these are all just convenience features of the object, not an actual array.

If you look at [the official examples](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php), you'll see that `$myElement->periods->period` is just short-hand for `$myElement->periods[0]->period`. So in most cases, you simply don't need to know if there are multiple children or just one, if you do `foreach($myElement->periods->period as $period)` for instance, the loop will always work. SimpleXML takes care of the different scenarios for you.

If what you really want to know is *how many* of a particular element there are, you can use `count($myElement->periods->period)`. But again, you should not need to have any special cases in your code for when there's only one.

Comment: I think your answer is ok. Anyway my assumption is not totaly wrong. Depending on the `$myElement` I process, if I have 2 or more `period` in `periods`, var_dump tells `["period"]=> array(2)`, so an **array** of objects. If I have only have one `period`, then var_dump says `["period"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)`. It is what I wanted to say and it's why I wondered how to use `is_array()`. But it seems I can use `foreach` in any case. Thanks.

Comment: @2ndGAB `var_dump` tells you that, but it's lying! There is no array there, it's just the way *the debug output* represents the fact that there is more than one child element with the same name. Under the hood, there's just a bunch of very un-PHP-like data representing the XML document, which is accessed on demand.